# Error al guardar datos en un struct

Tags: c, linux

Así declaro mi struct pero al momento de guardar me guarda dos veces el dato `int semaforo;`.

```
struct mystruct
{
  char arr[MAXBUF];  
}es;

struct mystruct *entrada;

char g[20]={"11111111111111111118"};
```

Así lo guardo  y lo imprimo:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    strcpy ( entrada[i].arr, g);
}

{
    printf("%s\n",entrada[0].arr);
}
```

... y me sale:

```
1111111111111111111811111111111111111118
11111111111111111118
```

... y debería salir:

```
11111111111111111118
11111111111111111118
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1):

Hay varios problemas con tu código.

El primero es que necesitas dejar un carácter libre en tu buffer para el NULL  (\0) que el compilador coloca al final de cada string. Por lo tanto en tu linea:

```
char g[20]={"11111111111111111118"};
```

Deberías agrandar el buffer a 21 o escribirle un carácter menos.

Como segundo pronlema, estas confundiendo punteros con arrays.

Empecemos por el principio:

```
struct mystruct { char arr[MAXBUF];
}es;
```

Ahí lo que estas haciendo es definir tu estructura (tipo de dato nuevo). Es importante entender que esa definición no reserva espacio en memoria, ya que no declara ninguna variable. (Permíteme decir que es muy extraño declarar una estructura para sólo colocar un array dentro de ella, pero ignoremos eso por ahora)

Luego haces lo siguiente:

```
struct mystruct *entrada;
```

Acá si estas declarando un variable, pero lo que estas declarando es un puntero a una estructura, es decir eso sólo te permitirá almacenar direcciones de memoria de otras estructuras, y por lo que veo en tu código no es lo que quieres hacer.

Lo que necesitas es un array de estructuras y deberías declararlo de la siguiente manera:

```
struct mystruct entrada[2];
```

De esa manera declaras un array de estructuras que te permitirá almacenar dos de ellas.

Para imprimir todos los datos contenidos en la estructura, también tendrías que realIzar un for como hiciste para cargarlo:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    printf("%s\n",entrada[i].arr);
}
```

Realiza esos cambios y debería funcionar

Answer (score 0):

Tienes múltiples fallos; lo misterioso es que no te de un error de protección general o un SIGSEGV.

```
struct mystruct *entrada;
```

Ahí estas creando **un puntero** a tu estructura, que inicialmente tiene un valor indeterminado y no sabemos donde apunta. Tu código no muestra como inicializas ese puntero.

```
strcpy ( entrada[i].arr, g);
```

Cuando `i == 0`, estas copiando el contenido de una cadena **sobre el primer elemento de un supuesto array de tus estructuras**, no sobre el primer elemento del array `arr` de tu estructua.

Cuando `i == 1`, estas copiando el contenido de una cadena **sobre el segundo elemento de un supuesto array de tus estructuras**, no sobre el segundo elemento del array `arr` de tu estructura.

```
strcpy( destino, origen );
```

Dicha función *recorre la memória, desde la posición marcada por `origen`, y va copiando bytes hacia el `destino`, secuencialmente* **hasta que encuentra un byte \0,** *que* **también** *es copiado*.

Eso quiere decir que, cuando tu haces

```
char g[20]={ "11111111111111111118" };

for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
 strcpy ( entrada[i].arr, g);
}
```

En realidad, estas copiando **2** veces **la cadena completa g[20]**, **empezando la segunda copia justo después de los datos copiados la primera vez**.

Si tu `entrada` es efectivamente un array, *ha dado la casualidad de que, por sus tamaño y alineamiento, sus espacios de memória estan justo uno detrás de otro*. Eso quiere decir que la *segunda* llamada a `strcpy()` **sobreescribe** el byte \0 que la primera llamada puso al final de `entrada[0]`. Esa sobreescritura hace que `printf()` no vea separación alguna entre las cadenas, y las muestre juntas.

Aunque en `C` los punteros y los arrays son equivalente, los estás mezclando de una forma, cuanto menos, *curiosa*.